# Control daily usage of an API for each user

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform

I grabbed the speech to text demo from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/SpeechRecognitionClient). I want to set a daily limit of API invocations for each user (user session). Is there any native Android way to do so ? I think it is feasible using Firebase creating for each user a session although not sure, am I right, but it would be a harness.

Isn't each install on a device unique, I think probably there some native solution for controlling APIs calls on user session.

I have no starting point, really, thus I have no code to share.

Answer (score 2):

1. use firebase authentication for authorising users to your app
2. use a google cloud cron jobs to update user quota every day
3. on requsts to your apis you could reduce 1 unit from quota and reject if there is any request more than the quota

Comment: I missed that this is not the solution, the problem with this is that cloud endpoints can be debugged by anyone, and then abused. So a server cloud level must be the solution not a client side solution. (I don't want to create a whole server for this, so I am still looking for what Google Cloud provides).

Comment: how could someone hack it? one can only call the API on their own behalf and then it ll always reduce their quota . use JWTs for API auth

Comment: run the app, with network traffic sniffer, take the internet request then fire it again with the same params

Comment: it ll be reducing the quota of the user then what's the problem ?

Comment: @Curcuma_ try to understand. on every request their quota will be reduced. and in the request there will be no data regarding the quota. it ll be queried from database when the request happens and then the quota will be updated in the database. so if a user ll call the api. he wont get anything instead he will be reducing his quota

Comment: So how to set a "user" quota limit. This is the core of the question ! this is why I am looking for capping API calls on a user scope

Comment: @Curcuma_ look at the answer. it covers everything one needs to cap api limit. thats how i had been doing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223404/discussion-between-curcuma-and-harkal).